# Issue while Booting into Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, data-recovery

Recently, my laptop automatically shutdown all of a sudden, and did a disk check while shutting down showing a lot of errors, then I had to force shutdown it.

Since then while booting Everytime either normally or in Recovery mode, the screen freezes and then shows the error message like "no such device" and "you need to load the kernel first".

Attached the screenshot of the error messages.

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Processor : Intel core i5 8th gen

Storage: 1TB HDD

RAM: 4GB+8GB(extra added)

Any methods to safely repair the issue without any data loss is highly appreciated.

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN6HI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can try from these 4 methods, this all methods will not affect your personal data on computer.

1. Go to advance in grub menu and try to run from different kernel available.
2. This happens when system files got corrupted or deleted. You can also use the bootable USB drive to repair your system that will be better.
3. You can also retrieve all your data from your system using the bootable USB drive.
4. There is one another way you can try:
   on grub menu press `e` to edit the start script and edit the line starting with `linux` where you have to change `ro` to `rw` (also remove everything after `ro` on that line.) and have to append `init=/bin/bash` at the end of line (this will open a terminal for you before starting) now press `Ctrl+X` or `F10` to boot.
   Now, run `update` and `upgrade` command from there and after upgrade run `sync` command and then restart your system. This can also repair your system.

Whatever you changed in method 4 will get removed on reboot or next boot so don't worry about it.

Comment: If you can get to a terminal an have internet access you may run `sudo aptitude reinstall '?priority(important)' && sudo aptitude reinstall '?priority(required)' && sudo aptitude reinstall ~E` This will reinstall any required, important and essential packages for your system. Maybe you need to install aptitude with `sudo apt install aptitude` first...

Comment: @starkus: I suggest you to develop this in a full answer.  Your comment deserves it.